# Override Enum metaclass initialization

Tags: python, enums

Although pylint raises a warning on `enum.Enum(value=..., names=...)`, I see from the enum doc that one could programmatically create an Enum like the following

```
import re
import enum
import termios

def termios_baud_rates():
    regexp = r"(?:^|,)B(?P<rate>\d+)"
    rates = sorted(map(int, re.findall(regexp, ",".join(dir(termios)))))
    return {"B{:d}".format(r): r for r in rates}

BAUD_RATES = enum.Enum("BAUD_RATES", termios_baud_rates())
```

But I'd also like to add methods:

```
@classmethod
def valid_rate(cls, value):
    return (any(value == item.value for item in cls))
```

I think this should involve overloading metaclass `__prepare__(mcls, names, bases)` to augment bases with the names dict, but apparently bases is not how the Enum attributes are created. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: Subclassing enums: https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-subclassing-of-enumerations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple using the [`aenum library`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)<sup>1</sup>:

```
import re
import aenum
import termios

class BaudRate(aenum.Enum):
    _ignore_ = 'cls regexp rates'

    cls = vars()
    regexp = r"(?:^|,)B(?P<rate>\d+)"
    rates = sorted(map(int, re.findall(regexp, ",".join(dir(termios)))))
    for value in rates:
        cls['B%d' % value] = value

    @classmethod
    def valid_rate(cls, value):
        return (any(value == item.value for item in cls))
```

The `_ignore_` tells `aenum` what to, um, *ignore* and, in fact, anything in `_ignore_` is removed from the final `Enum` class.

Due to a [bug in Python's Enum](https://bugs.python.org/issue31801) this doesn't yet work unless you use `aenum`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: thanks this is the sort of thing I'm looking for. If you have any good reference links or gists on how this works I'd appreciate it; I'm trying to get a better understanding of how metaclass works under the hood and its applicable to my current project (ex. constructing a standardized interface / protocol class with OS specific code inserted during instantiation)

Answer (score 2):

What if you create a new subclass of `Enum` instead?

```
from enum import Enum

class ValidEnum(Enum):

  @classmethod
  def valid_rate(cls, value):
    return (any(value == item.value for item in cls))
```

Or, depending on the use case, you could create another class that wraps the enum.

Either should work as follows:

```
In [3]: BAUD_RATES = ValidEnum("BAUD_RATES", termios_baud_rates())

In [7]: BAUD_RATES.valid_rate(0)
Out[7]: True

In [11]: BAUD_RATES.valid_rate(213)
Out[11]: False
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Icary  thanks for the example; I was hoping just to override either `__prepare__` or `__new__` in metaclass because this is the sort of thing that would call for them, i.e. changing how the Enum would be constructed before reaching class __new__ or __init__

Comment: Makes sense! Wasn't sure how entry-level the question was, but sounds like it was a bit more complex than a simple subclass, in which case the `aenum` library looks like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `nonlocal` to avoid needing the `aenum` package:

```
import re
import enum
import termios


regexp = r"(?:^|,)B(?P<rate>\d+)"
rates = sorted(map(int, re.findall(regexp, ",".join(dir(termios)))))

value = None

class BaudRate(enum.Enum):    
    nonlocal value
    for value in rates:
        locals()['B%d' % value] = value

    @classmethod
    def valid_rate(cls, value):
        return (any(value == item.value for item in cls))
```